# C++ sorting indices based on other information

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11

Say I've got a list of vertices: `std::vector<vec3> vertices`, and a list of indices: `std::vector<unsigned int>`. I then want to sort those indices with `std::sort`, not based on the size of the index, but based on the vertex coordinates they point to. This is what I mean:

```
std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 
        [](unsigned int indexA, unsigned int indexB) {
            return vertices[indexA].x < vertices[indexB].x;
        });
```

In a perfect world, the following would sort the indices based on the x-coordinate of the vertices pointed to. However, that's not how lambda functions work, I don't have access to the `vertices` information.

Is there a way to use `std::sort` in the way illustrated above? Or am I better off using a key-value data structure / implementing my own bubble sort?

Comment: Don't you just need to capture `vertices`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just miss the capture of vertices, a simple `&` in the capture part of the lambda.

```
std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 
    [&](unsigned int indexA, unsigned int indexB) {
        return vertices[indexA].x < vertices[indexB].x;
    });
```

Here how it works : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: All of a sudden, lambda functions seem way more useful... thanks!